# Sphinx-build error

Tags: compiling

I compile some apps on my machine and lately have been getting errors that docs can't be built. Seems to be related to sphinx. I get this error when I run sphinx-build:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sphinx-build", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('Sphinx==4.3.2', 'console_scripts', 'sphinx-build')())
  File "/usr/bin/sphinx-build", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 25, in <module>
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 43, in <module>
    from sphinx.registry import SphinxComponentRegistry
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sphinx/registry.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling python3-sphinx but nothing has worked so far.
I'd appreciate some help or advice.
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538412/12642499

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.